# Different CSS for different screen size?

Tags: javascript, css, html, media-queries

I was searching arround here and I found that I can use one of the following:

Adapt.js or Media Queries

I was wondering what is better to use? I Basically need to resize some specified divs with different width for different screens. (800x600 and 640x480)

If none of mentioned is good, any other solution ? Thank you :)

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130054/strategies-for-handling-multiple-screen-resolutions-and-aspect-ratios-in-web-dev There are some good points made

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="css/common.css">
<!--Responsive style sheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 800px)" href="css/name1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 640px)" href="css/name2.css">
```

Comment: Works great , simple and fast. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

you might be able to use something like this in CSS

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) {
   ... put your css here
}
```

The above is probably for mobile devices only

Comment: FYI: I use the above for an iPod/iPad interface. On iPad it shows splitscreen, on iPod it shows single screen

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning to support multiple screens I would recommend using 960 Grid [http://960.gs/](http://www.960.gs).

Comment: I am glad to help. I am using it for building Ipad and mobile screens.It has a day or two for your learning curve but you will be amazed with the productivity.Good luck

Comment: Well I don't understand anything so far with these column things :D ! 
Guess I'll read it on free time. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Media Queries are the best solution for you

[have a detailed info about these here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/responsive-web-design-guidelines-tutorials/)