# How to make JSF 2.0 application which supports more than one resolution

Tags: jsf-2

I am working on application for UI which uses JSF 2.0 and Primefaces 3.4. My UI should support more than one resolution like minimum it should support 1024 x 768 and it should support 1280 x 1024 as well.

Can someone please let me know how can I achieve this?

Comment: This is not related to JSF-2 at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is a HTML/CSS problem, not related to JSF or PrimeFaces.
Have a look at this:

- [Strategies for Handling Multiple Screen Resolutions and Aspect Ratios in Web Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130054/strategies-for-handling-multiple-screen-resolutions-and-aspect-ratios-in-web-dev)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design