# Detect window resolution on Mac and Surface

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my Surface and MacBook, I’ve set my resolution as 2160x1440, but my code:

```
$(window).height(); //return 960
$(window).height(); //return 1440
```

I have tested it on Windows, and it worked properly. What’s the issue here?

Comment: Are you using a Retinadisplay?

Comment: how about $(document).height(); ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are using a retina display.

You must use `window.devicePixelRatio` to calculate the real resolution.

edit : A lot of info about resolution and device pixel ratio at http://ryanve.com/lab/resolution/

Some important notes :

- devicePixelRatio definition differs by platform.
- `window.devicePixelRatio` is equivalent to dppx
- `window.devicePixelRatio` changes with zoom on desktops yet remains static on mobile devices. device-pixel-ratio media queries also differ as so.

Comment: window.devicePixelRatio always return value 1 :(

Comment: all browsers (chrome,safari...)

Comment: It should work at least for Chrome. They implemented it correctly. Which version do you use ? (don't know for other browser). Be sure to have zoom set to 100%

Comment: did you test on surface or macbook? i sure zoom set to 100%

Comment: On my MB Retina I'm seeing 2. Weird.

Comment: Combined with this test maybe you can go ahead : https://github.com/benlister/utilities/tree/master/Modernizr%20Retina%20%3a%20HiDPI%20test

Answer (score 2):

try `window.devicePixelRatio`

```
window.screen.width * window.devicePixelRatio; //Screen Width
window.screen.height * window.devicePixelRatio; //Screen  Height
```

Comment: Hello @john, I tried the same in windows and mac with a retina screen. It's working well in windows, But in mac with the retina display, my screen resolution is (3072 x 1920) and I am getting ( 3584 x 2010 ). So can you please tell me what would be the reason? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To check your viewport height use `window.innerHeight` or `window.outerHeight`. 
If you want to check your screen resolution, simply use `window.screen.height`. Pure JavaScript, no jQuery required.

Remember, that logical pixels aren't the same as physical pixels, especially at Mac's Retina display.

Comment: `window.screen.height` works for me after replicating the problem on my MacBook

Answer (score 0):

Kevin is actually right about the pixel ratio, but the solution he posted isn't cross-browser friendly. This is actually a slightly modified version of Adam's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20413768/3629748), but this should support more browsers. It uses media queries to determine what the pixel ratio is, but keep in mind that if you set an element to be that size, it will actually show up huge on a Retina or other high-density display.

```
var multiplier = 1;

if ((window.matchMedia && (window.matchMedia('only screen and (min-resolution: 124dpi), only screen and (min-resolution: 1.3dppx), only screen and (min-resolution: 48.8dpcm)').matches || window.matchMedia('only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2.6/2), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3)').matches)) || (window.devicePixelRatio && window.devicePixelRatio > 1.3)) {
    multiplier = 2;
}

var width = $(window).width() * multiplier;
var height = $(window).height() * multiplier;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'am using this:

```
  var screenResolution = window.screen.width + "x" + window.screen.height;
  var viewportSize = getViewport();

  var getViewport = function(a) {
             var c = document.documentElement,  e = document.body, g = e && e.clientWidth && e.clientHeight,  ca = [];
             c && c.clientWidth && c.clientHeight && ("CSS1Compat" === document.compatMode || !g) ? ca = [c.clientWidth, c.clientHeight] : g && (ca = [e.clientWidth, e.clientHeight]);
             c = 0 >= ca[0] || 0 >= ca[1] ? "" : ca.join("x");
             return c;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but you should be able to do something like this:

```
actual_resolution = $(window).height() * $(window).devicePixelRatio;
```

Answer (score 0):

With the `devicePixelRatio` you must get the correct resolution.

```
var devicePixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;

console.log(window.screen.width * devicePixelRatio); // Width
console.log(window.screen.height * devicePixelRatio); // Height
```

Answer (score 0):

This was my attempt at a cross-browser/platform dpi solution.  It uses a 1 inch fixed width/height cell to determine the number of pixels in it.

```
<script> 
function dpi(){ 
   var res={},div=document.createElement("div");
   div.style.position="absolute";
   div.style.width="1in";
   div.style.height="1in";
   div.style.left="-100%";
   div.style.top="-100%";
   document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
   res["xdpi"]=div.offsetWidth;
   res["ydpi"]=div.offsetHeight; 
   div="";
   return res; 
} 
res=dpi();
alert("xdpi="+res.xdpi+", ydpi="+res.ydpi) 
</script>
```