# Adjust Image Path based on Device Retina Ratio

Tags: jquery, css, retina, retina.js

I'm creating a site for a photographer and I'm creating a gallery at the moment. To save me a lot of code I've automated much, including file name, path, width, lightbox class, etc.

In the HTML I simply have to write an `<a>` with a title and the jQuery takes care of the rest.

**HTML**

```
<a alt="All-my-Loving"></a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    $('.imagesContainer a').each(function () {
        var $link = $(this),
            title = $link.attr('alt'),
            thumb = 'images/portfolio/thumbs/' + title + '.jpg';

    $link.attr('data-target', 'flare');          // for gallery plugin
    $link.attr('data-flare-scale', 'fitmax');    // for gallery plugin
    $link.attr('data-flare-thumb', thumb);       // for gallery plugin
    $link.attr('data-flare-gallery', 'main');    // for gallery plugin
    $link.addClass('item');                      // for IsoTope/Packery/Masonry
    $link.attr('href', 'images/portfolio/full/' + title + '.jpg'); // Link to full image

    $link.append($('<img>', {
      src     : 'images/portfolio/thumbs/' + title + '.jpg'    // Link to thumbnail image in gallery
    }));
    });
});
```

**The problem:**
However, the image path leads to regular (@1x) images and as I want to make this site retina-proof the path should lead to an @2x or @3x image when the device has an retina screen.

As far as I know, although haven't exactly tried, [Retina.js](http://imulus.github.io/retinajs/) is not an option since this only works for inline-images, but all images get their src image path after the above script is executed.

**One single must:**
It doesn't matter how to achieve retina images instead of regular ones for retina devices, as long as not a single image is downloaded twice (1x and 2x, simultaneously).

Who got a clue?

---

**Possible (theoretically) solution:**
In addition to the above JS script, simply have an IF statement

```
If (window.devicePixelRatio > 1) {
    $link.append($('<img>', {
      src     : 'images/portfolio/thumbsRETINA/' + title + '.jpg'
    }));
} else {
    $link.append($('<img>', {
      src     : 'images/portfolio/thumbsREGULAR/' + title + '.jpg'
    }));
}
```

And apply that IF statement to check if the device is Retina to each ImagePath request.

---

**Update**
I've applied the above IF statement and it's working. The RetinaFolders are empty and my iPhone 6 is showing no images (as there are none). I'm just not sure if that's the right way to go. The new script becomes:

```
$(function () {
    $('.imagesContainer a').each(function () {
        var $link = $(this),
            title = $link.attr('alt'),
            thumb = 'images/portfolio/thumbs/' + title + '.jpg';
            retinaThumb = 'images/portfolio/thumbs-retina/' + title + '.jpg';

    // regular tags
    $link.attr('data-target', 'flare');
    $link.attr('data-flare-scale', 'fitmax');
    $link.attr('data-flare-gallery', 'main');
    $link.addClass('item');
    $link.attr('href', 'images/portfolio/full/' + title + '.jpg');

    // Retina tags
    if (window.devicePixelRatio > 1) {                  // If the device has retina graphics
        $link.attr('data-flare-thumb', retinaThumb);
        $link.attr('href', 'images/portfolio/full-retina/' + title + '.jpg');
        $link.append($('<img>', {
          src     : 'images/portfolio/thumbs-retina/' + title + '.jpg'
        }));
    } else {                                            // If the device does not has retina graphics
        $link.attr('data-flare-thumb', thumb);
        $link.attr('href', 'images/portfolio/full/' + title + '.jpg');
        $link.append($('<img>', {
          src     : 'images/portfolio/thumbs/' + title + '.jpg'
        }));
    }

    });
});
```

Comment: I usually just load a 2x image at a 1x (50%) resolution. This is definitely an interesting problem in FE though.

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall That's indeed  how it works. However, loading 2X images for a 1X device (regular 1080p desktop) is a waste of bandwidth. Combine that with hundreds of images, both thumbnail and full size, is a waste of tens to hundreds of MB's per page view. :) Therefor looking for a waste-free solution.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I don't see how that would fit my solution, since I (think I) can't apply that to the above JS script / images..

Comment: @SanderSchaeffer I completely agree on the waste of bandwidth. I have not found an easy-to-implement solution yet though for this issue. :|

Answer (score 1):

Here's a theoretical answer. You will have to adapt it to your needs.

Add a `data-retina-src` attribute to each image (works in jQuery):

```
<img src="image.jpg" data-retina-src="image2X.jpg" alt="">
```

Use jQuery media queries and switch image source with `data-retina-src` source.

**EDIT 1:**

Check these links for jQuery retina detection:

http://egorkhmelev.github.io/retina/

[What is the best way to detect retina support on a device using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19689715/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-retina-support-on-a-device-using-javascript)

**EDIT 2:**

Use this script - http://imulus.github.io/retinajs/ - and check for alternate images automatically:

> For example, if you have an image on your page that looks like this:
>   `<img src="/images/my_image.png" />`
>
> The script will check your server to see if an alternative image
>   exists at this path: "`/images/my_image@2x.png`"

Comment: Can jQuery out-of-the-box detect if the device has retina graphics (DevicePixelRatio>1) and if true, serve the Retina-src instead of the regular src? Update: I just noticed the situation is a bit more complicated. Not only the img src should be adjusted to retina, but the image (via an <a>) is clickable and also the href of the <a> should be adjusted if the device is retina. However, this is half the solution already :)

Comment: I have edited my answer. You could also add an alternate `href`, as `data-retina-href`.