# Bootstrap 4 grid system on retina screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, retina-display

i have div like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-xl-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 px-0 p-4">
```

When i test it on 27' screen it uses `col-xl-2` and it works perfect, but when i test it on 13' screen of macbook pro with `retina` screen it uses `col-xl-2` too and it looks weird. How i can handle this stuff and specify column size for retina screens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
col-md-4
```

or

```
col-sm-4
```

[Bootstrap documentation (Grid)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/)

**Update**

The large screen is detected due to the high resolution of the retina display.

You  can set your own `breakpoints` in Bootstrap.

[Customizable Bootstrap 3.3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/)

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165713/high-resolution-devices-display-extra-small-bootstrap-layout) answer could point you to the right direction.

Alternatively try this ([source](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/)):

```
@media 
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
(min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
    /* Retina-specific stuff here */
}
```