# how to load a high res image if the client is high dpi/aspect ratio

Tags: html, image, dpi

What I'd like to do is load "normal" images on my site if a visitor is, for instance, on a monitor constrained device like a smartphone.  But if they're on a big monitor with high DPI I'd like to load a high-res equivalent image.  Preferably from the server-side or some way that doesn't require an extra step at load time so images still load as quickly as possible.

There are some questions about how to detect retina/high DPI devices using javascript: [What is the best way to detect retina support on a device using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19689715/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-retina-support-on-a-device-using-javascript) or on the server: [detect retina (HD) display on the server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234519/detect-retina-hd-display-on-the-server-side) but I want to apply that info to load the appropriate image client side.

Answer (score 0):

Retina.js may be helpful, if you're looking for client side solutions.

http://imulus.github.io/retinajs/